# I want to create an application that shows all the applications that were launched

Tags: android

Time and Name of application opened

```css
final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
 packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
 
 for(ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages )
 {
    String name=packageInfo.getClass().getName();
    Toast.makeText(ListActivity.this, ""+ name, 0).show();
 }
```

Comment: could you detail a lil' bit more?

Comment: I want to create an application that will list all the applications that were opened in my phone, i.e. if i open 5 apps then my app should list all the 5 apps opened and at what time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to get the list of running apps.

```
ActivityManager activity_manager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
```

Use `getRunningTasks()` method from `ActivityManager`.

```
final ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
final List<RunningTaskInfo> recentTasks = activityManager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

for (int i = 0; i < recentTasks.size(); i++) 
{
    Log.d("Executed app", "Application executed : " +recentTasks.get(i).baseActivity.toShortString()+ "\t\t ID: "+recentTasks.get(i).id+"");         
}
```

Add this permission in the manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" ></uses-permission>
```

Comment: I want which app was clicked at what time.

Comment: what pemission should be given in ManifestFile